# My SCSS stylesheet isn't linking to my HTML

Tags: html, sass

I have trouble linking my scss(sass) stylesheet to my html. The scss file is in the same folder as my index.html.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the scss in css?

Comment: If you don't know how to do that just edit your answer and add the scss code and I'll compile it

Comment: you should give information to us, we don't know what you have done, send ur HTML page header at least. I have to mention that u should convert ur SCSS to CSS first then link the CSS to HTML

Comment: I put a line of my code into the question, but for some reason it didn't display. Here it is : 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="styles.scss"/>

Why do I need converting?

Comment: SCSS is a compiler, you can't directly use it in your HTML code. You have to use the file that SCSS compiler produces which is in CSS format. Look at https://sass-lang.com/install for steps on how to install. Usually, for development purpose its common practice to use something like webpack or gulp.

Comment: Because HMTL only understands CSS and Not SCSS. Hence you cannot use SCSS directly with HMTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scss needs to be compiled for css, search for gulp or grunt

Gulp: https://gulpjs.com/
Grunt: https://gruntjs.com/