# My styles.scss is not working in html at all

Tags: html, css, sass

I have added
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.scss">`
i have already installed sass in my computer.
and the  code in styles.scss are fine.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My SCSS stylesheet isn't linking to my HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904339/my-scss-stylesheet-isnt-linking-to-my-html)

Answer (score 0):

Sass need to be compiled before using it in your html page. Is it just a simple html page you'r setting -up

Answer (score 0):

Once Sass is installed, you can compile your Sass to CSS using the sass command. You'll need to tell Sass which file to build from, and where to output CSS to. For detail information go through this doc https://sass-lang.com/guide.

Answer (score 0):

Click Watch sass button (After Installing Live Sass Compiler in VS Code).